# Check existence of a post by id in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an id:

```
$id = 151;
```

I want to check existence like this:

```
$content = get_post($id);
if ($content)
    echo "post $id already exists";
else
    echo "post $id does not exists or was deleted";
```

But in the WP forums always seems prefer ask to DB:

```
global $wpdb;
$post_exists = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE id = '" . $id . "'", 'ARRAY_A');
if ($post_exists)
    echo "post $id exists";
else
    echo "post $id does not exist";
```

So which is the best method? Indeed I prefer the ease of the first one.

Comment: I believe that it is very irresponsible to not consider the efficiency of the calls as they processed on the server. Generic C/C++ implementations are not usually optimized for everything and the scalability of calls must be taken into consideration. There is a balance between optimization and maintainability, but to make an open statement that the PHP world should not care about resource usage is just naive and ultimately lazy. You can take your argument to an extreme and have a team of php programmers' put out junk code and rest on the assurance that the underlying OS libraries are going to

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think if they give you a function to a call, you call it; use the database for things that aren't provided by a function.

Comment: +1 Yes, I think the same but search for `wordpress check if post exists` and appears a lot of solutions like the second one in the `http://wordpress.org/support`

Comment: I feel your instincts are correct, and cannot explain why someone would recommend the other way. Only way of knowing would be to ask someone who recommends that. I'd be curious to know the answer, if you ever hear of one.

Comment: OK my friend let's do it in the right way, using the API. @Pekka thinks the same too (why he deleted his answer?). Cheers!

Answer (score 51):

I think the best is to query the database directly as less as possible

You can use the get_post_status() function.

It returns false if the post doesn't exist

```
if ( get_post_status( $post_id ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

or, to be sure that the post is published

```
if ( 'publish' === get_post_status( $post_id ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_status/

Comment: I checked the source of `get_post_status` and it uses `get_post`. Why not just directly use `null !== get_post( $post_id )`?

Comment: @Michelle I was thinking the same, but it returns a bunch of extra data. Wouldn't it be just as clean to do what csag suggested? Either way is clean and uses Wordpress and not the wpdb. :)

Comment: I almost always agree with the sentiment that you should avoid a direct DB query when possible. But in this case, I think it's worth writing a custom function that will be more efficient than `get_post`. The core function `post_exists` calls the DB directly, so I think we should do the same to check if a post id exists. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328684/947370

Answer (score 6):

```
if( is_null(get_post($id))){

      echo "post $id does not exists or was deleted";

}else{

       echo "post $id already exists";

}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Comment: Be aware that with this approach posts in the trash are still considered as existing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class for an efficient, SQL-free solution:

```
$id = 151;

$post_exists = (new WP_Query(['post_type' => 'any', 'p'=>$id]))->found_posts > 0;

if ($post_exists)
    echo "post $id already exists";
else
    echo "post $id does not exists or was deleted";
```

Note that both [get_post_status](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_status/#source) and [get_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/#source) load extraneous data.

Comment: This is less efficient the calling the database directly, but it's good practice to make use of WP_Query where possible. You can improve the efficiency slightly by adding a 'fields' => 'ids' parameter.

Comment: If you decide to use WP_Query here - see https://10up.github.io/Engineering-Best-Practices/php/#performance 

Using these would be a big performance improvement as WP_Query actually makes 4 database queries by default. `'no_found_rows' => true,
'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
'update_post_term_cache' => false,
'fields' => 'ids',`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old post, but still... If you want to check if post with certain id exists you can also use get_permalink wordpress function.

Example:

```
if( get_permalink( $post_id ) ):
echo "does exist";
else:
echo "does not exist";
endif;
```

Notice that get_permalink function also returns page, attachment links and not only posts.

Comment: Worth noting that get_permalink() calls get_post. So if you are doing this for performance reasons, it still does that same get_post() call anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to look to the existing core code for inspiration here.
There is a function already for [post_exists](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/) but it only checks titles, content, status, etc. You can [see the full source here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L777).

Notice that for the purpose of just checking if something exists, the code in the core does indeed directly query the database and only pull the ID - not all of the data for the entire post. This is **very efficient** and worthy of copying this method. Here's what I came up with:

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists( 'post_id_exists' ) ) :
    function post_id_exists( $post_id ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $post_id = (int) $post_id; // cast as INT to sanitize
        if ( $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=%s", array( $post_id ) ) ) ) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
endif;
```

The accepted answer says "query the db directly as little as possible". In broad strokes for new WordPress developers this is good advice. But I think the better advice is to avoid scattering a bunch of repetitious direct database calls across your custom code, and to avoid direct database calls when there's an existing function that already does exactly what you are looking for. In this case we have found an instance of a function that maybe we wish was in the core but there's no efficient way to do it with core functions. For this rare case, we should write a function that queries the database, and use the core code as a model for how to do it efficiently and securely.

`get_post`, `get_permalink` and other functions recommended here all have specific purposes that will be way less efficient than a purpose built function with a query built to be as fast as possible. And as other commenters noted - some other suggestions like `get_post_status` actually call `get_post` inside of them, so that's even less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer querying the database over the get_post call.

The post content may be of great size.  Querying and pushing the entire content of the post into a string just to check to see if it exists is incredibly wasteful and inefficient.

If you don't want to query the database directly, maybe using get_post_field to pull one of the smaller fields would be just as effective, but less wasteful.

Comment: I don't think that in the PHP world we should care too much about the resources uses. Leave that for C programmers. PHP and MySQL are enough clever to manage it by they own. There are other considerations like DRY and the cleaning of the code. THX

Comment: It's not a question of PHP and MySQL managing resources.  It's a question of the programmer imperatively consuming unneeded resources.  It's like using SELECT * everywhere.  The just grab everything attitude will eventually break you on anything but little itty bitty sites, especially if your database and HTTP servers are on different hosts.